# A ruby SPARQL query that SELECT(s) all triples for a given subject

Tags: ruby, rdf, sparql

I'm using the following ruby library to query a SPARQL endpont.
http://ruby-rdf.github.io/sparql-client/

I'm really close to achieving what I want. With the following code I can get a print out of all the triples in my database.

```
sparql = SPARQL::Client.new("http://localhost:3030/ds/query")
query = sparql.select.where([:s, :p, :o]).offset(100).limit(1000)
query.each_solution do |solution|
puts solution.inspect
end
```

But now I want to change this just slightly and select all the triples for a given subject. I thought the following would work, but it doesn't.

```
sparql = SPARQL::Client.new("http://localhost:3030/ds/query")
itemname = "lectio1"    
query = sparql.select.where(["<http://scta.info/items/#{itemname}>", :p, :o]).offset(100).limit(1000)
query.each_solution do |solution|
puts solution.inspect
end
```

This would work in a straightforward SPARQL syntax, but somehow replacing the symbol :s with the literal subject I want queried doesn't work. The error that Sinatra gives me is:

> expected subject to be nil or a term, was `"<http://scta.info/items/lectio1>"`;

Comment: http://sparql.rubyforge.org/client/SPARQL/Client/Query.html see the `where` method. this might help somehow, I can't quite decipher it

Comment: OK, you've got an answer now (and I'm going to delete some of those comments)

Answer (score 1):

As you noted in the comments,

> The error that Sinatra gives me is: expected subject to be
>   nil or a term, was `"<http://scta.info/items/lectio1>"`

You're pasing the method a string, but it's expecting `nil` or a term.  The kind of term that it's expecting is an [RDF::Term](http://rdf.rubyforge.org/RDF/Term.html).  In your particular cases, you want a URI (which is a subclass of RDF::Resource, which is a subclass of RDF::Term).  You can create the reference that you're looking for with

```
RDF::URI.new("http://scta.info/items/#{itemname}")
```

so you should be able to update your code to the following (and depending on your imports, you might be able to drop the `RDF::` prefix):

```
sparql = SPARQL::Client.new("http://localhost:3030/ds/query")
itemname = "lectio1"    
query = sparql.select.where([ RDF::URI.new("http://scta.info/items/#{itemname}"), :p, :o]).offset(100).limit(1000)
query.each_solution do |solution|
  puts solution.inspect
end
```